# AppBarLayout overlaps RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

I have been searching for quite a while to resolve this issue without success. My AppBarLayout is overlapping the RecyclerView in one of my xml files. I have tried rearranging the views without any positive results. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/bg_register">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:id="@+id/x"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the xml file of content:

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/bg_register"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity">

    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/list" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_recycler"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: It seems to be pushing the Toolbar off of the screen from what I can tell. See pic: https://postimg.org/image/80mfleobl/

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you feel that the recyclerview is touching the bottom of the screen, then just add a suitable `layout_marginBottom` for the recyclerview.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear that I need to see the toolbar on top of that view. The toolbar isn't showing up at all. As I mentioned, the toolbar is being pushed off of the view completely.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add this attribute to the include below the toolbar:

```
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

When you are using `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout`, you are setting up for that coordinated scrolling where the toolbar pushes out of the way first.  But in  order to get that, you need to give the view below the toolbar the appbar scrolling view behavior.  This not only sets up the coordinated scroll, but tells the `CoordinatorLayout` to layout the lower view so that it appears beneath the toolbar.

If you don't want the coordinated toolbar scrolling, replace `CoordinatorLayout` with a vertical `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same overlapping problem but the reason for this was that i've had

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

as my root ViewGroup, not

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

so check for that as well :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look overlapping. Just add margins to content from the main xml if you want to have spaces in between. Also, remove orientation from root Relative Layout from content xml since it wouldn't work.